# Java client throwing A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field error

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregate

I have the below code to perform and upsert on the MongoDB collection.
upsert operation contains $set, $increment and $cond also.

```
 try (MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create("mongodb://localhost:27017")) {

        MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("DBName");

        MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("collCourse");

        Document globalFilter = new Document();

        Document updateQuery = new Document();

        System.out.println("Connected to DB");

        globalFilter.append("status", "Open");

        Date eventDtm = new Date();

        Document appendDoc = new Document();

        Document ds = new Document("$set", appendDoc.append("sn", "CS"));

        appendDoc.append("rp", "Invalid");
        appendDoc.append("ldtm", new Date());
        appendDoc.append("dtim", "9876");

        updateQuery.putAll(ds);

        /** Increment fields **/
        Document incrementOps = new Document("$inc",
                        new Document("dv", 10).append("pc", 1).append("tc", 1).append("tv", 2).append("tb", 3));

        updateQuery.putAll(incrementOps);

        /** conditionaly update Start and End Dtm **/
        Document updateSdtm = new Document("$set", new Document().append("sdtm", new Document("$cond",
                        Arrays.asList(new Document("$lt", Arrays.asList(eventDtm, "$sdtm")), eventDtm, "$sdtm"))));

        Document updateEdtm = new Document("$set", new Document().append("edtm", new Document("$cond",
                        Arrays.asList(new Document("$gt", Arrays.asList(eventDtm, "$edtm")), eventDtm, "$edtm"))));

        updateQuery.putAll(updateSdtm);
        updateQuery.putAll(updateEdtm);
        
       
        collection.updateMany(globalFilter, Arrays.asList(updateQuery), new UpdateOptions().upsert(true));
        
        System.out.println("Done");

}
```

while running this I am getting an error

> com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 40323
> (Location40323): 'A pipeline stage specification object must contain
> exactly one field.' on server localhost:27017. The full response is
> {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "A pipeline stage specification object must
> contain exactly one field.", "code": 40323, "codeName":
> "Location40323"}  at
> com.mongodb.internal.connection.ProtocolHelper.getCommandFailureException(ProtocolHelper.java:205)

I tried multiple ways. Could someone suggest the best way to perform upsert with increment and set(with condition) operators?